# MVC4 Area returning 404 only on IIS and not everytime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

So I built a new ASP.NET MVC4 application, some really simple stuff. I added an Area for administration purposes. Everything works fine when I debug on Visual Studio's IIS Express.

The problem comes when I deploy this application on a Windows Server 2012's IIS, most of the time, when I try to acces my Area I get a 404 error. The weired thing is sometimes, after redeploying the application (but not changing anything), the area will work for a certain amount of time (until the application pool gets recycled maybe ?)

Anyway this is really weired and I'd need a hand on this. Here's what I've done :

Here is my `RouteConfig` for the base application :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NewsFilter",
            url: "Articles/{tagName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", tagName = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "myapp.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "ViewArticle",
            "Article/{articleId}/{articleTitle}",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", articleTitle = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { articleId = @"\d+" },
            namespaces: new[] { "myapp.Controllers" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "myapp.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Now here's my `AdminAreaRegistration` for the Admin area

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin_default",
            url: "Admin/Home/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new []{ "myapp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin_news",
            url: "Admin/News/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="News", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "myapp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin_Tags",
            url: "Admin/Tags/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Tags", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "myapp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Now here id the `Application_Start` method from `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); //This registers the admin Area

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); //I did not delete WebApiConfig even though I'm not using it
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //And here are my "normal" routes
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

All the controllers from my Admin area are in the namespace `myapp.Areas.Admin.Controllers`. The main app controllers are in the namespace `myapp.Controllers`.

On IIS, the app pool for the application is running in .net 4.0 Integrated mode.

Any idea why the area is working in debug mode, working *sometimes* on IIS and returning 404 *most of the time* ?

Comment: I would suspect the way it is deployed. Does the file exist in that location.

Comment: Yes it does, I always double checked for differences before and after deployment and didn't notice anything. Also wouldn't explain the fact that sometimes a random restart of the application teporarily fixes the problem. My guess is sometimes the area is registered at application start, sometimes it's not. But why ?